# Cannot access cookie in axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, sveltekit, js-cookie

I've got a function that creates a cookie (I'm using sveltekit):
`src\routes\api\auth\+server.js`:

```
import {login} from "../../../api/auth.js";
import {loginDTO} from "../../../business/data-transfer-objects/login.js";
import {emptyObject} from "../../../helpers/index.js";
import {errorResponse, successResponse} from "../../../core/response.js";
import {AUTH_TOKEN_KEY} from "../../../core/consts.js";

/**
 * User Login -> if 200 returned from the server then save the returned token
 * into a cookie.
 * @param event
 * @returns {Promise<Response>}
 * @constructor
 */
export async function POST(event) {

    const data = await event.request.json();

    // validate and create DTO.
    const loginData = loginDTO(data);
    // if errors returned from building the DTO (validation errors) then return the object.
    if (loginData?.errors && !emptyObject(loginData.errors)) {
        return errorResponse(data, loginData.errors, 422)
    }

    // perform login.
    const response = await login(loginData);

    // if login is not successful then return error.
    if (response.status !== 200) {
        // remove password from data.
        delete data["password"];
        return errorResponse(data, response, response.status);
    }

    // if login is successful then set the auth cookie.
    event.cookies.set(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, response.data.token, {
        // send cookie for every page
        path: '/',
        // server side only cookie so you can't use `document.cookie`
        httpOnly: false,
        // only requests from same site can send cookies
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSRF
        sameSite: 'strict',
        // only sent over HTTPS in production
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        // set cookie to expire after a month
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    })

    return successResponse(response.data, 200);
}
```

this is called from an `actions` function when my login form is submitted:

```
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";

/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {

    default: async ({request, fetch}) => {

        const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());

        const res = await fetch('api/auth', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        const response = await res.json()

        // todo CV-127: once dashboard page is implemented that's the place where this action shall be redirected to.
        if (response.status == 200) {
            throw redirect(302, '/')
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

the cookie is successfully created (see image):

```
championship-access-token   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlYXQiOiIyMDIzLTA1LTIyVDAxOjI4OjMwLjk0MzAwMTE3MloiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODQ3MTY5MTAsImlkIjo3fQ.VaVfzgnib0DhzRO8jUJ-X_2BRIiAGXIq8eEQOs85anI localhost   /   6/20/2023, 8:55:10 PM   192 B       ✓   Strict
```

[image: cookie]

Now, I've created an axios interceptor since I want to retrieve the token stored in the cookie and attach it to my requests. The problem is that I cannot access the cookie. I'm using `js-cookie`, and the interceptor looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export const app = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1",
    timeout: 1000,
    params: {},
});

app.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        console.log("interceptor -> retrieving cookie:");
        Cookies.set("test123", "asdasdasd")
        console.log(Cookies.get(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY));
        console.log("test cookie: ", Cookies.get("test123"))
        console.log("cookie: ", Cookies.get(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY));
        console.log("ALL COOKIES", Cookies.get())
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        Promise.reject(error)
    }
);
```

In the code above I'm not trying yet to attach the value of the cookie, I'm simply trying to retrieve it at the moment but it's always `undefined`. I tried to create a new cookie using `js-cookie` but doesn't seem to work. Notice that the original cookie was created using a cookie helper from Sveltkit which I cannot access at this point (or at least I don't know how since it's only accessible from server side files), reason why I decided to use `js-cookie`.

Any idea what's going on? Perhaps is the `import` the one that I got wrong? I already tried:
`import * as` Cookies `from 'js-cookie'` yet the result is the same.

One more thing which I don't know if it's relevant to the question: notice this param used to create the cookie:

```
httpOnly: false,
```

even though it is set to `false`, the cookie is set as `httpOnly` (see screenshot).

Thanks

Comment: the reason your axios can't access the cookie is clearly because the httpOnly is set to true, your real problem lies on the fact that the cookie setter in the sveltekit failed to set it to false. Can you maybe try to tweak the `maxAge` value to arbitrary number and see if the cookie setter change the `maxAge`?

Comment: @MrCujo Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of the issue you're having. More specifically, the function call you provided that shows how you set your cookie is not enough information to reproduce your issue. Please provide more details so that we can help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you need to use axios for another purpose? Or do you use axios because you want the cookie to be accessible front-side?

Comment: @Damzaky I set `maxAge` to 30 and the change is visible via dev tools. Not sure why `httpOnly` is not set correctly to false though.

Comment: @Andria in this case is quite difficult to provide a minimal reproducible example since there are many files involved, but the code sample I provided comes from the server (the one where i set the cookie) and the other one from the frontend (where I access the cookie). I know it's not much but again, for this specific case providing a working piece is quite difficult

Comment: @Ennoriel currently using axios only to intercept all requests going to the backend (written in Go) and add the auth token stored in the cookie

Comment: I know that it's impossible to make a minimal reproducible example for this, since this requires server, but honestly it's also hard to debug it just from seeing the code. By the looks of it, if you could set the `httpOnly` to false, your problem will be solved instantly

Comment: @MrCujo We need to see more of what's going on in your server. The `event.cookies.set` line does not give us enough information to identify why the `httpOnly` cookie is being set to `true`. Like where are you calling it from? Also you might not need to access the cookie from your JavaScript code given that it should be automatically attached anyway.

Comment: ok guys, you're right. I added more code that might help with the context. Let me know if that helps or if i still need to add more. Thanks

Comment: @MrCujo I still can't reproduce your issue. Using `event.cookies.set` with `httpOnly: false` works when I tried it. [Here is a CodeSandbox of what I tried.](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/andria-dev/svelte-cookies-demo/main) Perhaps you could provide a CodeSandbox that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to add `withCredentials: true,` to `axios.create` options:

```
export const app = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1",
    timeout: 1000,
    params: {},
    withCredentials: true, // Add this line
});
```

By adding `withCredentials: true` to the `axios.create` options, Axios will include the cookie header in cross-origin requests, allowing the server to read and set cookies.

Regarding the cookie creation: you need to ensure that the interceptor is executed after the cookie is set. Interceptors are executed for every request, so if the cookie is set after the interceptor is called, it won't be available in the interceptor's context.

You can try the following modified interceptor code to troubleshoot the issue:

```js
app.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        console.log("Interceptor -> Retrieving cookie:");

        // Wait for the cookie to be set
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

        console.log("All cookies:", document.cookie);
        console.log("Test cookie:", Cookies.get("test123"));
        console.log("Token cookie:", Cookies.get(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY));

        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

By introducing a small delay using `setTimeout`, you allow some time for the cookie to be set before retrieving it. This delay can help ensure that the interceptor runs after the cookie has been set.

Regarding the `httpOnly` flag, setting it to false in your code doesn't guarantee that the cookie won't be treated as `httpOnly`. The `httpOnly` flag is a security measure that prevents client-side JavaScript from accessing the cookie. It is typically enforced by the server, and if the server sets the `httpOnly` flag to true, the client-side code won't be able to access the cookie.

Comment: ok, but what about when the cookie is already set? shouldn't be picked up instantly? I mean, after login the cookie is stored, then the next intercept should simply be able to read it and that's not happening